# Append content to new browser window from the parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, html5-canvas

I am trying to integrate a cropping tool to my website (js plugging [resizing cropping images canvas](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/10/30/resizing-cropping-images-canvas/)). This tool will let the user crop an image, open it in a new browser page, and give him the capacity to save the new image into the disk.

The cropping code is as following:

```
crop = function(){
    //Find the part of the image that is inside the crop box
    var crop_canvas,
    left = $('.overlay').offset().left - $container.offset().left,
    top =  $('.overlay').offset().top - $container.offset().top,
    width = $('.overlay').width(),
    height = $('.overlay').height();

    crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    crop_canvas.width = width;
    crop_canvas.height = height;

    crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, width, height);
    var newWindow = window.open(crop_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
}
```

Now i want to append some HTML content to newWindow body, but it does not work. I tried to add the following after `window.open` command:

```
var text = document.createTextNode('Hello World !');
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(text);
```

But nothing is added to the new page ?

How can add stuff to the body of the new page using the script from the parent page ? (Html content and even some javascript code)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var dataUri = crop_canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
    newWindow = window.open("about:blank");

newWindow.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\n<body><img src='" + dataUri + "' /></body>");

var text = document.createTextNode('Hello World !');
newWindow.document.body.appendChild(text);
```